# number of elements strictly lesser than a given number

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I want a data structure in which I want to insert elements in log(n) time and the elements should be sorted in the ds after every insertion. I can use a multiset for this.

After that I want to find the numbers of elements strictly smaller than a given number again in log(n) time. And yes duplicates are also present and they need to be considered. For example if the query element is 5 and the ds contains {2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8} then answer would be 3(2, 2, 4) as these 3 elements are stricly lesser than 5

I could have used multiset but even if I use upper_bound I will have to use distance method which runs in linear time. How can I achieve this efficiently with c++ stl. Also I cannot use

Comment: *if I use upper_bound I will have to use distance method which runs in linear time* <- What do you mean by this?

Comment: by using upper_bound I can find the iterator pointing to next greater element than query element. Let the query element is 5 and next greater element is 7. Once index of 7 is known I can find index of smaller element than 5. but then to find the index I have to use std::distance method which runs in linear time. If this doesn't make sense please ignore this. Tell me your approach

Comment: Using your example in the question, you could call `lower_bound(5)` and you have the range, no?

Comment: You cannot use the standard library for this, you need a balanced tree that stores weights of its left and right subtrees (or just the left subtree for your case) and makes them available via some kind of API.

Answer (score 3):

The data structure you need is an order statistic tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

The STL doesn't have one, and they're not very common so you might have to roll your own.  You can find code in Google, but I can't vouch for any specific implementation.